# Chart.js - 2 datasets in line chart always show tooltips?

Tags: javascript, charts

How to always show tooltip BUT with 2 datasets for line chart?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/454/) which works with one dataset.

My tooltip code is:

```
var options = 
{
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",

    showTooltips: true,

    onAnimationComplete: function()
    {    
        this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].points, true);          
    },
    tooltipEvents: []
}
```

And in same appirience I would like to have with 2,3 or more datasets.

Here is [jsfiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/457/) where I tried 2 datasets.

I guess, this line has something to do with it:

```
this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].points, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find a solution. Here it is: [Chart JS: Always show tooltips in a multi dataset line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793540/chart-js-always-show-tooltips-in-a-multi-dataset-line-chart)

But if you want to do the same thing but on Bar chart, you need to change:

```
for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < this.datasets[0].points.length; dataIndex++) {
```

to

```
for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < this.datasets[0].bars.length; dataIndex++) {
```

and from

```
dataCollection = dataset.points;
```

to

```
dataCollection = dataset.bars;
```

At the bottom you should call Bar chart, eg.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(dataBar, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
}
```

Comment: Can you please refer where should I use this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I am not following. Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, this is not something that I am need. As you can see in my first jsfiddle example - I want tooltip, BUT for chartjs to be visible all the time. It works when I have one dataset but when I have more, it only shows first value. thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not something that I need. Here is what I need http://jsfiddle.net/5gyfykka/454/