# ChartJS always show combined tooltip in position 'average' for multiple datasets in line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using the latest ChartJS version (2.8.0). I need to always display two specific tooltips, in position: 'average', without hover, like so:

[Expected: permanent tooltip to show points between dotted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcj9g.png)

But this is all I managed to do so far:
[Current: permanent individual tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtAFz.png)

I've consulted this [thread (Chart JS: Always show tooltips in a multi dataset line chart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793540/chart-js-always-show-tooltips-in-a-multi-dataset-line-chart) but was unable to use the code to generate any combined tooltip at all.

I also tried the single dataset code provided for doughnut charts [provided here (Chart.js - Doughnut show tooltips always?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661197/chart-js-doughnut-show-tooltips-always), but this is giving me the individual tooltips instead.

```
          var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')
          Chart.plugins.register({
    beforeRender: function(chart) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // create an array of tooltips
            // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
            chart.pluginTooltips = [];
            chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
                    chart.pluginTooltips.push(
                        new Chart.Tooltip(
                            {
                                _chart: chart.chart,
                                _chartInstance: chart,
                                _data: chart.data,
                                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                                _active: [sector]
                            },
                            chart
                        )
                    );
                });
            });

            // turn off normal tooltips
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    },
    afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
        if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
            // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
            if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                if (easing !== 1) return;
                chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
            }

            // turn on tooltips
            chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
            Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
                tooltip.initialize();
                tooltip._options.mode = 'index';
//            tooltip._options.position = 'average';
                tooltip.update();
                // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                tooltip.pivot();
                tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
            });
             chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
        }
    }
});

          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
              datasets: [{
                label: 'Votre portefeuille',
                data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, , , , ],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(17, 43, 55, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(17, 43, 55, 1)',
                pointRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                fill: false
              }, {
                label: 'Votre portefeuille à la performance du marché     ',
                data: [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, , , , ],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(108, 162, 54, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(108, 162, 54, 1)',
                pointRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                fill: false
              }, {
                label: 'DOTTED Votre portefeuille',
                data: [, , , , , 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(17, 43, 55, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(17, 43, 55, 1)',
                borderDash: [5, 5],
                pointRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                fill: false
              }, {
                label: 'DOTTED Votre portefeuille à la performance du marché',
                data: [, , , , , 9, 11, 13, 15, 17],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(108, 162, 54, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(108, 162, 54, 1)',
                borderDash: [5, 5],
                pointRadius: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                fill: false
              }]
            },
            options: {
              // responsive: true,
              aspectRatio: 1.5,
              showAllTooltips: true,
              // showTooltips: true,
              tooltips: {
                position: 'average',
                mode: 'label',
                intersect: false,
                filter: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  if (tooltipItem.xLabel === '9' || tooltipItem.index === data.labels.length - 5) {
                    return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 2
                  } else {
                    return ''
                  }
                },
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(17, 43, 55, 1)',
                bodyFontStyle: 'bold',
                bodyAlign: 'center',
                borderWidth: 1,
                xPadding: 12,
                yPadding: 12,
                // yAlign: 'top',
                xAlign: 'right',
                displayColors: false,
                callbacks: {
                  title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return ''
                  },
                  beforeLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 2) {
                      var total = 0
                      total = Math.round((parseInt(data.datasets[2].data[tooltipItem.index]) - parseInt(data.datasets[3].data[tooltipItem.index])) / 100) * 100
                      if (total < 0) {
                        return 'Manque à gagner'
                      } else {
                        return 'Surplus'
                      }
                    }
                    return ''
                  },
                  label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 2) {
                      var total = 0
                      total = Math.round((parseInt(data.datasets[2].data[tooltipItem.index]) - parseInt(data.datasets[3].data[tooltipItem.index])) / 100) * 100
                      if (total < 0) {
                        return total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ') + ' $'
                      } else {
                        return total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ') + ' $'
                      }
                    }
                    return ''
                  },
                  afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return ''
                  },
                  labelTextColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
                    if (parseInt(chart.config.data.datasets[2].data[tooltipItem.index]) < parseInt(chart.config.data.datasets[3].data[tooltipItem.index])) {
                      return '#F31919'
                    } else {
                      return '#6CA236'
                    }
                  },
                  opacity: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return '0'
                  }
                }
              },
              // hover: {
              //   mode: 'nearest', // null if no hover? filter type none? enabled false?
              //   intersect: false
              // },
              legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                reverse: true,
                labels: {
                  usePointStyle: true,
                  fontSize: 16
                }
              },
              layout: {
                padding: {
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  top: 30,
                  bottom: 30
                }
              },
              scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  gridLines: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Année',
                    fontSize: 16
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false,
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    padding: 20
                  }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  gridLines: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Valeur marchande $',
                    fontSize: 16
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                      return value.toLocaleString('fr-CA') + ' $'
                    }
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          })
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codingmi/u1qhmofe/) contains the desired positioning for the tooltips, but they need to be hovered on.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codingmi/1j2t6ev9/136/) has the permanent tooltips, but individual/right next to the points instead of between the 2 lines.

I can't seem to find information for multitooltips beyond threads from 3 years ago, and am having trouble going through the github code for tooltip generation. Any help would be appreciated.