# Always Enable Tooltip : Chart JS : V3 : Bubble Chart : react-chartjs-2

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to always enable all the tooltips for Bubble chart using react-charjs-2 plugin

I tried various approaches but none of them work with the latest version of the plugin

Would appreciate some advice, Thank you! :)

I tried the all possible approaches, including the following ones, but was unable to achieve the results

Tried the following:

- [Chart JS: Always show tooltips in a multi dataset line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793540/chart-js-always-show-tooltips-in-a-multi-dataset-line-chart)

Answer (score 0):

By default it is not possible to show all the tooltips at once, if you really want it you will need to use the external (html) tooltip.

The easyer way is to use the datalabels plugin: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bubble.html