# Unable to display point values without mouse hover

Tags: javascript, laravel, callback, chart.js

Herewith I used `JavaScript` line chart within `Laravel` framework. Mouse hover tool tip to display point values working perfectly with `label:function(...)`. I need to display only y-axis value on every point at chart on create (Without mouse hovering). To perform this I used `drawDatasetPointsLabels()` method from [How to display Line Chart dataset point labels with Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870963/how-to-display-line-chart-dataset-point-labels-with-chart-js) and call it on chart `options`. But unfortunately it is not working. Below is the code.

**chart.blade**

```
monthlabels={.......};
salesqty = {......};
stockqty = {......};

document.getElementById("history_canvas_holder").innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
document.getElementById("history_canvas_holder").innerHTML = '<canvas id="historyChart" width="500" height="350"></canvas>';
var ctx = document.getElementById("historyChart").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, 
{
  type: 'line',
  data: 
  {
      labels: monthlabels,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Sales',
          data: salesqty,
          borderColor: [
              'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
          label: 'Stock',
          data: stockqty,
          borderColor: [
              'rgba(0,161,232)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 2
      }
      ]
  },
  options: {
      tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
              label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

                  if (label) {
                      label += ': ';
                  }
                  label += Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100;
                  return label;
              },
              onAnimationProgress: function() { drawDatasetPointsLabels(ctx) },
              onAnimationComplete: function() { drawDatasetPointsLabels(ctx) } 
          }
      }
  }                  
});

function drawDatasetPointsLabels(ctx) {
  ctx.font = '.9rem "ABCD",sans-serif';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#AAA';
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  $(historyChart.datasets).each(function(idx,dataset){
      $(dataset.points).each(function(pdx,pointinfo){
          if ( pointinfo.value !== null ) { 
              ctx.fillText(pointinfo.value,pointinfo.x,pointinfo.y - 15);
          }
      });
  });         
}
```

Comment: That is a very old question (over 4 years old) and probably is no longer relavant. If you are needing to have labels shown for each of your points, maybe you should look at using the popular Chart.js plugin for labels: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Answer (score 0):

In the type of v2.5.0

```
`options: {
    tooltips: {
         enabled: false
    }
}`
```

or

```
`tooltips :{
            custom : function(tooltipModel) {
                tooltipModel.opacity = 0;
            }
 }`
```

type of v2.1.4

```
`Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;`
```

people said those ways are work, but not in all charts type.